# Requested Contact not displaying in the conversejs web client

Tags: ejabberd, converse.js

I have added a friend request (Add To Contact) with the following command.

sudo ejabberdctl add_rosteritem rohit localhost test localhost test none none

And While getting the contact it showing as below,

sudo ejabberdctl get_roster rohit localhost

---

ashwin@localhost    ashwin@localhost    both    none

girish@localhost    girish@localhost    none    out

test@localhost  none    none    none    none

---

But test@localhost is displaying neither in the "Pending contacts" nor in the "Contact Request" in Web client GUI for both rohit and test user.

Comment: Try adding rohit@localhost to test@localhost's roster as well, so that the subscription is mutual, then check again. I think the reason it's not showing might be because the subscription is only one way.

Comment: Can you please provide me command here to request a user just like a behind process of "Add To Contact" from web client?

Comment: I don't think there is such a command for ejabberdctl.